# manipulating a char* in c

Tags: c

This is my program and it is seg faulting when i try to do s[0] = s[1]. 
I don't understand why this wouldn't work as all i am doing is taking value in s[1] and putting it in s[0].

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
  char x;
  char *s="stackoverflow";

  s[0] = s[1];  // it is segfaulting here 
  x = s[0];  //this works though 
  printf("this is: %s\n",s);
}
```

i am compiling using gcc filename.c and running it using ./a.out in ubuntu terminal.

Thank you.

Comment: Attempting to modify a string literal causes undefined behaviour in C.   This question is a duplicate hundreds (or maybe thousands) of times over.

Comment: BTW: main() should return int, not void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do: `char *s="stackoverflow";` then **s is a pointer that points to a memory that is in the code part**, so you can't change it. Because it's *read-only*, you're getting segmentation fault at runtime (if you used the `const` keyword, you would get a compilation error, which is better.. So it's recommended to use `const` if you don't want to make changes on strings).

If you do `char s[]="stackoverflow";` then **s is an array of chars that are on the stack**, so you can change it.

Comment: This is to say that the string is not defined on the heap as it would be had you malloc'd a buffer and then attempted to modify on the heap, which is legal.

Comment: Whether it's read only or not will depend on the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You should not attempt to change a string literal. If you want to modify the value, make a copy using `strcpy` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Change declaration of variable:

```
char s[] = "stackoverflow";
```

will remove the problem you have, as variable will have storage allocated on entering the scope and initialized with the data given.